# Keep a dropdown menu visible until clicked outside of it with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using Jquery to display a dropdown menu onMouseEnter a navigation link, I wrapped onMouseEnter with hoverIntent:
 
https://github.com/briancherne/jquery-hoverIntent 
(used to control sensitivity of OnMouseEnter without using OnMouseOut as that's not what I want):

I want jquery code to close dropdown menu when **clicked** outside of that dropdown menu or onMouseEnter another navigation link.

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zNPbRp 
JSFiddle: 
 https://jsfiddle.net/6jc6pjLu/1/

Structure:
 *-I have two navigation links that carry a dropdown menu, one with a class MySecondLink, the other with a class MyThirdLink.*

 *-Dropdown menus, one with a class MySecondLinkTabLinks, the other with a class MyThirdLinkTabLinks*

**jQuery Process:**(onMouseEnter a navigation link, replace class value "PopupClosed" with "PopupOpen" on navigation link for styling purposes, and replace display:none; with display:block; on dropdown menu to show it) that is the process of displaying the dropdown menu, Closing it (replace PopupOpen with PopupClosed on navigation link and replace display:block; with display:none; on dropdown menu) :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var config = {   
     sensitivity: 1, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)   
     interval: 100,  // number = milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval   
     over: doOpen,   // function = onMouseOver callback

/* Don't want onMouseOut from hoverIntent */ 
//    timeout: 0,   // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut   
//     out: doClose    // function = onMouseOut callback  
};

function doOpen() {
    $(this).removeClass('PopupClosed').addClass('PopupOpen');
    var cls = $(this).data('target'); // fetch data-target value.
    $('.Menu.' + cls).css('display','block'); // will make display block
}

/* Commented out because I want to apply another approach for closing the menu as doClose() depends only on mouseOut.

function doClose() {
    $(this).addClass('PopupClosed').removeClass('PopupOpen');
    var cls = $(this).data('target'); // fetch which class to target.
    $('.Menu.' + cls).css('display','none'); // will make display none
}

*/

$(".navTab.Popup").hoverIntent(config);
});
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mRqxJa I created this codepen for someone yesterday. Looks similar to your issue. Can you look if it helps you.

Comment: Could you try to isolate whether this is a css problem, or a javascript problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to keep submenus visible until clicked outside of that submenu. You need to do followings:

1. Remove `out: doClose` from `config` so that your submenus stays visible after hover menu items.
2. But you need to add `$('.Menu').hide();` top of the function `function doOpen() {....}`
3. Add these script which will allow to hide opened submenus on body click.

   `$(document).click(function(event) {
       $('.Menu').hide();
     });`

https://codepen.io/avastamin/pen/XpzQXB

Comment: You got the idea, go ahead and implement the rest. let me know how far your progress.